# Do the hint flags in glBufferData actually do anything?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es

The flags I am talking about are GL_STREAM_DRAW, GL_STATIC_DRAW and GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.  [The manual page is clear about when you should use them but ambiguous about what will happen if you do](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml).

Now before you all answer too quickly, let me state that I understand what they are supposed to do, and could imagine some hypothetical scenarios where it might be important.  But I am skeptical that it makes much of a difference in practice.  Lately I've been thinking that it would be nice to just set the flag to GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW and forget it, but there is a nagging doubt in my mind that I might be shooting myself in the foot if I do that.

Does anyone actually know more **specifically** what these things do?  In particular I am most curious about the difference between STATIC_DRAW and DYNAMIC_DRAW.  Is picking the wrong one a framerate death trap or are they just placebos?  I imagine that any real answer is going to be conditional on the actual driver implementation.  Alternatively if you can come up with a real world example where these flags do something (anything really) then I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: Note: that man page is woefully out of date. And I'm not talking about the fact that it is only OpenGL 2.1. [The maintainer of the man pages has stated that they will not be fixing any errors in the 2.1 pages.](http://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=464#c1) So you should refrain from using them.

Comment: It is good to know, but I don't think glBufferData has changed much in the last couple of years.  I figured I'd post a link instead of giving a page number for the reference pdf.  Do you know a better source for the manual pages?

Comment: I got sick of the maintainer's slow pace in fixing errors, so [I uploaded the whole thing to the OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Category:Core_API_Reference), where errors can be fixed as they are discovered, rather than waiting. This only exposes the *core* OpenGL API, not the compatibility. If you want to use the "official" 4.3 core API reference, [that's available here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/). I just wish they'd take down the old pages if they're not going to keep them up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

The usage hints will never have any behavioural change. The most they will do is change the performance of various operations. And perhaps not even then.

For example, [the usage hints were so misused that AMD effectively *ignores* them](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1174329#1174329). They will move the memory around based on how you *use* the buffer, not based on the usage hint. NVIDIA's drivers are a lot less willing to compromise.

In general, the only way to know which usage hint to use for maximum performance is to *profile* it. You pick which hint gives you the best performance.

Comment: That's an interesting reference, though a bit sketchy.  Do you have any more information, especially about what happens when you set STATIC_DRAW vs DYNAMIC_DRAW?

I fully understand the need to profile and test things to select the optimal configuration and I know that the flags don't change rendering behavior, but that is not what I am asking here.  What I want to understand is what happens internally if I pick one flag over another and know how it affects performance.  (And if that post is credible, then it seems like at least on AMD hardware as of 2010 nothing...)

Comment: This might be a per-platform thing, as far as support goes. I know that the Apple engineers I talked to were pretty clear about their iOS devices using certain optimizations with `GL_STATIC_DRAW`, and that does seem to be reflected in what I've seen within my own applications. They talk about these extensions in detail in their own OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW5

Comment: @BradLarson:  Again nice to know.  Performance wise, what happens with these optimizations?  Do they slow down when you issue a bunch of updates or use more memory?  Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @Mikola - All I can say is that I did a quick benchmark on one of my applications on an iPhone 4, and I see a ~4-5% performance improvement using `GL_STATIC_DRAW` over `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` on a geometry-limited rendering with static vertices and normals. That's not a huge difference and is just barely above the noise in my timing process.