# Hot to Fill Output Buffer in OpenGL Compute Shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-es, gpu

I want to calculate some values in my compute shader and return them to a heap allocated buffer on CPU side.

I send 5 float numbers in an array named as "input_buffer" to GPU with my compute shader and I want to multiply all values by 3 and 6 in that array.

The problem is I can't fill my output buffer even if I bind it correct corresponding binding index in my Compute Shader code.

This is my code -->

```
const char* compute_shader = "\n" \
        "#version 430 core\n" \
        "layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;\n" \
        "layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer input_layout\n" \
        "{\n" \
        "   float Elements[];\n" \
        "};\n" \
        "layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer output_layout\n" \
        "{\n" \
        "   float Elements2[];\n" \
        "};\n" \
        "void main()\n" \
        "{\n" \
        "   const uint idx = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;\n" \
        "   Elements2[idx] = Elements[idx] * 3.0f;\n" \
        "   Elements[idx] = Elements[idx] * 6.0f;\n" \
        "}\n" \
        "\n";

    uint32_t shader = CreateShader(compute_shader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    //int len = width * height;
    int len = 5;
    float* input_buffer = new float[len];
    float* output_buffer = new float[len];

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
    {
        input_buffer[idx] = 65.0f;
        output_buffer[idx] = -1001.0f;
    }

    GLuint SSBO;  //Shader Storage Buffer Object
    glGenBuffers(1, &SSBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, len * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)input_buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, SSBO);

    GLuint SSBO2;
    glGenBuffers(1, &SSBO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, len * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)output_buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, SSBO2);

    glUseProgram(shader);

    glDispatchCompute(len, 1, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT);

    float* dummy_out = nullptr;
    dummy_out = (float*)glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
    
    printf("\nInput Buffer: ");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
    {
        printf("%f ", input_buffer[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nOutput Buffer: ");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
    {
        printf("%f ", output_buffer[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (nullptr != dummy_out)
    {
        printf("\nDummy_Output: ");
        for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
        {
            printf("%f ", dummy_out[idx]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);
    delete[] input_buffer, output_buffer, dummy_out;
```

And the output is -->

```
OpenGL Version: 4.3.0 - Build 31.0.101.2114

Input Buffer: 50.000000 50.000000 50.000000 50.000000 50.000000

Output Buffer: -1001.000000 -1001.000000 -1001.000000 -1001.000000 -1001.000000

Dummy_Output: 150.000000 150.000000 150.000000 150.000000 150.000000
```

Why I can't see the changes in my buffer named as "output_buffer"? Is there any way to fill it on specially? This is what I need.

I tried other GLenum flags to get data.

Comment: Do not apply suggestions from an answer to the question. This will make the answer useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood how buffers in OpenGL work. Buffers contain a **copy** of the array passed to `glBufferData`, they do not establish any connection with between the buffer and the array. So when the buffer is changed, these changes are **not** reflected in the original array.

If you want to consume GPU generated data on the CPU side, you have to read the buffer content back with `glGetBufferSubData`, for example:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO2);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, len * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)output_buffer);
```

Please also note, that you probably need to add a memory barrier after the shader execution to make sure that the GPU has finished before reading the content back.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I edited the code in the right way. 
And as a last favor, Can you explain to me right usage of GLenum types like GL_DYNAMIC_COPY, GL_STATIC_DRAW etc...? Or can you direct me a pellucid documentation please?

Comment: The enum is only a hint for the GPU on how you intend to use the buffer. It may or may not be used by the GPU driver to decide where it places the buffer. The functionality of the buffer is not affected. See [Do the hint flags in glBufferData actually do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222458/do-the-hint-flags-in-glbufferdata-actually-do-anything)